# How can I delete/vote down/flag an outright wrong tag synonym?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

How can I delete an incorrect tag synonym, flag it, or vote it down?

The tag synonym in question is "https -> tls", its incorrect because HTTPS is HTTP over TLS/SSL, and it's a bit wrong to mix questions that are tagged with HTTPS, with for example questions that are about SMTPS (SMTP over TLS/SSL).

I would agree on the tag synonym if HTTPS was widely misused as a synonym for TLS/SSL, but I don't think so. It's better to fix the few questions that do have an incorrect "https" tag for a non-HTTP protocol over TLS/SSL, because autofixing all "https" tags to "tls" means a question about for example a security vulnerability or security rule only applicable for HTTP tunneled over TLS/SSL (for example CRIME or mixed-content rule) would get sorted under same questions to for example SMTP traffic over SSL, and it's not really right.

Answer (score 4):

Synonyms are not just for words that mean exactly the same - they are also for words that are likely to be used to refer to the same questions, or for search terms people are likely to use to find posts.

So for this one, I don't see a reason to change it - the synonym is helpful for the usage it is intended for.